# VisualStudio2017 C# クラス配列をMarshalAs指定することは可能ですか？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

以下のサンプルソースのようなデータ構造をクラスで構築したいと思っていますが
マーシャル指定したサイズが期待通りに動作しない状態です。

```cpp
    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Value
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public byte[] memberA;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
        public int[] memberB;
        public Value()
        {
            this.memberA = new byte[2];
            this.memberB = new int[7];
        }
    }

    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Data
    {
        public int type;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public Value[] values;
        public Data()
        {
            this.values = new Value[10];
        }
    }
```

具体的に問題となっている箇所は、Dataクラスの Value 配列でマーシャル指定してるサイズが正しく処理されず、おそらく4byte*10の値になっています。

> [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
>   public Value[] values;

マイクロソフトのドキュメントによると、ByValArrayは ”要素が構造体にフィールドとして定義されている配列でのみ使用できます。”となっているため使用できなさそうなのは理解しましたが、他のやり方でサイズを正しく処理できる方法がないかと思い質問させていただきました。

なお、構造体でなくクラスでデータ構造を構築したい理由は、引数なしのコンストラクタで、各配列要素のエリア確保を行いたいためです。

Comment: SizeConstで指定したサイズと配列要素数とがことごとく一致しないのはあえてでしょうか？ また `4byte*10` が何の値を指しているのかもわかりませんでした。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。要素数は修正しました。4*10の10は配列要素数で4は実行した結果から判断しました。

Comment: 古い記事で解決はしていませんが結論は出ているようです。あと1か月で消える記事ですが [C# クラスの配列を含むクラスをマーシャリングする方法](https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/1021) 「諦めて C#側のを struct で定義して下さい。class で定義した場合は何をどうやっても値として扱うことはできません。常にポインタとして扱われます。」

Comment: あるいは英語版の記事でこちら等。[C# passing an array of reference type objects to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42201137/9014308), [Marshalling array of structs vs classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9883308/9014308), [Marshal C# Class Array as Struct Array To C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8036719/9014308)

Comment: このデータ構造の用途は、ネイティブに渡すためですか？ 逆にネイティブから受け取るためですか？ 「引数なしのコンストラクタ」が必要な理由もあわせて知りたいです。それによって何か対策があるかもしれません。

Comment: 用途は上記の構造をバイト配列に変換し、TCP接続している別マシンに送信、または別マシンからのTCP送信されたバイト配列を上記構造に流しこんでいます。引数なしコンストラクタを使用したい理由は、上記構造を使用する側で配列要素を確保したくないだけです。（構造体自身を生成する static な new 関数を準備し使用してもいいかもしれませんが、使用者側が意識して static new関数を呼び出すこともしたくなかっただけです）

Comment: 古いAPIですがこの記事を応用するとか。[メンバに配列を持つ構造体のマーシャリング](http://schima.hatenablog.com/entry/20090620/1245425357) 同種の新APIはこちら。[Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure__1_System_IntPtr_), [Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(T, IntPtr, Boolean)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_StructureToPtr__1___0_System_IntPtr_System_Boolean_)

Comment: いろいろと有益な情報をありがとうございました。今の私では解決に時間がかかりそうなので、今回は、struct を使用して対応することとしました。
理由としては、上記構造を管理している entityまたはmessageクラスを準備しているため、そのクラスに使う側で必要なアクセッサをすべて準備し対応するようにしました。
また、本構造は、とあるCPPで作成されたソースコードをrubyスクリプトでパースし自動生成しているので、enitity等もある程度 ruby 側で自動生成するように修正しました。